# Mixing an "app controller" and ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I posted this question here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41521/mixing-an-app-controller-and-ng-view
As per package's recommendation.

Is there anything wrong with doing something like this in Angular?

```
<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
   <div ng-show="!loggedIn">
     <form ng-submit="login()">...</form>
   </div>
   <div ng-show="loggedIn">
       <div ng-view></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I'm using it right now on a project.  AppCtrl is used to control the active page in the navigation (using Bootstrap's navbar) and it handles showing the login form when a user isn't authorized, or showing the content when they are...

I can see how it might be discouraged, as I believe you could have a conflict between the AppCtrl controller and the controller currently "in charge of" ng-view... Of course, I'm being careful not to do that, but I'm wondering if there are any other good reasons to not do this, and what people might suggest as an alternative...

I'm hoping the answer is "no" because it's working beautifully for me! =)

Comment: I think this belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ya learn something new every day. Thx package! =)

Comment: if it works, it works. though, you definitely want to make sure everything you write is maintainable and easily understood by a new developer if they were to come into the picture. after all, that is a major reason developers use design patterns to architect applications.

Answer (score 1):

Check this authentication [service](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/), it's a way to handle authentication cleanly.

Plus it's better to use ng-switch rather than ng-show/ng-hide:

- ng-show and ng-hide - use if you only need to show or hide something (modifies CSS)
- ng-switch - use instead of using several mutually exclusive ng-shows (modifies DOM)

So a user can simply change one css property and access unauthorized content ....

I hope this answered your question (the answer is yes unfortunately)

Comment: Also ng-if is working better, also modifying the DOM instead of css